`lookupTransform` Fails to Find Transform in Composable Node with Namespace in ROS 2
Question:
I’m encountering an issue where lookupTransform cannot find a transform when running a composable node with a namespace in ROS 2. The error message is:
Could not transform from base_link to lidar_link: "base_link" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.

The issue only occurs in this specific setup. When I run the same code as a regular node (with or without a namespace) or as a composable node without a namespace, it works correctly.
Here’s the relevant code snippet:
geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped transform_stamped;

try {
    transform_stamped =
      tf_buffer_->lookupTransform("base_link", "lidar_link", tf2::TimePointZero);
    RCLCPP_INFO(
      this->get_logger(), 
      "Transform from base_link to lidar_link:\n"
      "  Translation - x: %f, y: %f, z: %f\n"
      "  Rotation    - x: %f, y: %f, z: %f, w: %f",
      transform_stamped.transform.translation.x,
      transform_stamped.transform.translation.y,
      transform_stamped.transform.translation.z,
      transform_stamped.transform.rotation.x,
      transform_stamped.transform.rotation.y,
      transform_stamped.transform.rotation.z,
      transform_stamped.transform.rotation.w);
} catch (const tf2::TransformException & ex) {
    RCLCPP_INFO(
      this->get_logger(), "Could not transform from base_link to lidar_link: %s", ex.what());
}

I’ve created a package to reproduce and debug this issue. For more details, please check the repository: https://github.com/YumaMatsumura/tf_test.git.
Any help would be appreciated!

Try using this API: https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2/blob/22d24021e21d4ade7c19fd65de006d2cbae22e3f/nav2_bt_navigator/src/bt_navigator.cpp#L68
  tf_ = std::make_shared<tf2_ros::Buffer>(get_clock());
  auto timer_interface = std::make_shared<tf2_ros::CreateTimerROS>(
    get_node_base_interface(), get_node_timers_interface());
  tf_->setCreateTimerInterface(timer_interface);
  tf_->setUsingDedicatedThread(true);
  tf_listener_ = std::make_shared<tf2_ros::TransformListener>(*tf_, node_shared_ptr, false/*or true*/);

This is what we use in Nav2 and what I see most commonly used and that definitely works :-)
[1] https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/rolling/tf2_ros/include/tf2_ros/transform_listener.h#L96-L99

Thank you for the suggestion! I modified the code as you recommended:
tf_listener_ = std::make_shared<tf2_ros::TransformListener>(*tf_buffer_, this, false);
After making this change, lookupTransform now works correctly in the composable node with a namespace. The issue is resolved.
I appreciate the help!
